# Send multiple ajax data from dynamically generated fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, grails

How can I send multiple data from dynamically generated fields in ajax?

Since I can't know the number of fields in advance I used a for loop which doesn't work for me.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data:{
                expectationPercentagePairId: JSON.stringify(expectationPercentagePairIds),
                expectationScores: expectationScores,
                for(var id in expectationPercentagePairIds){
                    score-${id}: $("input[name='score-'+id]")
                }
            },
            url:'${g.createLink( controller:'review', action:'saveReview', params:[id: params.id] )}'
        });
```

Comment: u can pass data as an array/json

Comment: The names of the fields is different. can I pass the array with the name of the field the data came from?

Comment: what is the content of this expectationPercentagePairIds?

Comment: It is an array and the name of the fields is score-id. Here id is a changing value.

Comment: yan u can still send it, expectationPercentagePairIds : expectationPercentagePairIds

Comment: The one that I want to send isn't expectationPercentagePairIds, rather it's a list of score-id value. I used expectationPercentagePairIds to get the names of the fields.

Comment: What I want to pass is a list of map of name : value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop wont work here. You could pass all form data using serialize and then handle the data on the backend.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data:{
            $('form').serialize()
        },
        url:'${g.createLink( controller:'review', action:'saveReview', params:[id: params.id] )}'
    });
```

Comment: just like what i said, but he didnt want it that way

Comment: @YidnekachewWondimu Good to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

If your dynamically generated fields are in a static parent element, you can find all inputs like `$("#perantelem").find('input')`  and then you can filter with your id(score-${id}) and generate key/value(name : value) array or json